# Enable JMX in jboss 6.1.0.GA

Tags: jmx, jboss6.x

I am trying to enable jmx in jboss 6.1.0.GA, to enable it I am adding below entry in standalone.bat file

```
**set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xbootclasspath/p:%JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logmanager\main\jboss-logmanager-1.4.0.Final-redhat1.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\system\main\jboss-system-jmx.jar
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=19999"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.rmi.server=192.168.85.134"**
```

After that I am getting following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("console-handler" => "CONSOLE")
]): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator cannot be cast to org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence
        at org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence.getOrCreateConfigurationPersistence(ConfigurationPersistence.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence.getOrCreateConfigurationPersistence(ConfigurationPersistence.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingOperations$LoggingOperationStepHandler.execute(LoggingOperations.java:154)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:440) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:322) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:229) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:224) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:334) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.0.Final-redhat-1]
```

I found a bug in jboss 6.1.0 which is fixed in 6.1.1 in below  link
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=969530

I want to know if is there any workaround available to enable jmx in jboss-6.1.0.

Comment: You can access via remoting-jmx see http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/11/01/connecting-visualvm-with-a-remote-jboss-as-7-eap6-jvm-process/. On the other hand its configuration is incorrect try change `Djava.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"` by `-Djava.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"`

Comment: Finally I am able resolve the issue, In jboss 6.1.0 JMX is enabled by default we don't need to change any configuration, What we need to change is add all the jboss jars which is included in jconsole.bat under %jboss_home%/bin folder and you can connect by below code( default jmx port is 4447) JMXServiceURL address = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:remoting-jmx://" + hostname + ":" + port);
Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();
 String[]  credentials = new String[] {"admin", "root1234@"};ht.put (JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, credentials);
connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(address,ht);